# GitHub Action job step failed with `Error: The log was not found.` message instead of expected log files

Tags: github-actions

The [CI GitHub Action](https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/actions/runs/4447793131/jobs/7887591232) ran for over an hour, with one of the job steps failing after running for 45 minutes. However, when checking the job logs, an error message was displayed instead of any output from the running step:

[image: Test - Error: The log was not found. It may have been deleted based on retention settings.]

*Error: The log was not found. It may have been deleted based on retention settings.*

This error message is preventing me from troubleshooting the failing step. The job log retention settings are set to 90 days, so it's unlikely that anything should have been deleted. The job was run hours ago.

How can I troubleshoot this failing step despite the "log not found" error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That step of your task is dumping too much to logs, the storage space of the VM is exceeded, and the process is unstable.

Reduce the amount you are, or are able to, dump to logs.

Comment: While it seems like there was a bug in the GitHub UX as I mentioned in answer, I think this advice is a decent starting point for the host of issues that could occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue too.

maybe this is because your log content is too large, and there is no left space to write logs.

you can see the error message from this link: https://${YOUR_GITHUB_RPOSITORY}/actions/runs/${action_id}

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the raw log files via `Download log archive` in the options menu, they will contain information that isn't visible on the webpage.

[image: Download log archive preview]

Comment: In this case, the step that corresponded to the failure `11_Test.txt` was over 500mb due to a failure message that was repeated for every test `java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Wed Feb 16 16:19:25 UTC 2022`.  I suspect the step output exceeded a size threshold that truncated the log output and cause the preview not to appear.